Can I access a container in a pod in an AKS cluster as root?
I have a usecase in which I need root access to a container running on an aks node.
The kubectl exec command does not support a user option:
PS C:\Repos\GetShifting\work> kubectl exec -it kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg -c grafana -u root -- /bin/bash
error: unknown shorthand flag: 'u' in -u
See 'kubectl exec --help' for usage.

I can use kubectl debug as described here to access the host:
kubectl get pods kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg -o wide
kubectl debug node/aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss000033 -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/cbl-mariner/busybox:2.0
chroot /host

Then on the host I want to do a docker exec command as a different user, like this:
docker ps
root@aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss0000033:/# sudo docker ps
sudo: docker: command not found
# so this one ain't going to work neither
docker exec -it -u root <dockerid> /bin/bash

Then I tried to show all containers running with the crictl command, and get the full container id from the correct container:
root@aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss000033:/# crictl ps | grep grafana
6439882b3402a       f9095e2f0444d       6 days ago          Running             grafana                           0                   75ba31cfe2863       kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg
658d77517b020       2e6ed1888609c       6 days ago          Running             grafana-sc-datasources            0                   75ba31cfe2863       kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg
fc35630b1f362       2e6ed1888609c       6 days ago          Running             grafana-sc-dashboard              0                   75ba31cfe2863       kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg
root@aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss000033:/# crictl ps --verbose --id 6439882b3402
ID: 6439882b3402a66761dde073c60721cca3ce89f9e2332a9ca4da3e8cbb268dec
PodID: 75ba31cfe28639a688f06693b7120faccef4bb1a724ed1e8cb01b1cb4bcdc881
Name: grafana
Attempt: 0
State: Running
Image: sha256:f9095e2f0444d50d16f3d1a1bb52ca4a6971ba7359fe78e0f0247c3dc70047cc
Created: 6 days ago
Labels:
        io.kubernetes.container.name -> grafana
        io.kubernetes.pod.name -> kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-7d448f8457-wr9gg
        io.kubernetes.pod.namespace -> vtxops
        io.kubernetes.pod.uid -> 5b01fe35-bbbb-46c1-a56d-cc156e426ec5
Annotations:
        io.kubernetes.container.hash -> 9661435a
        io.kubernetes.container.ports -> [{"name":"grafana","containerPort":3000,"protocol":"TCP"},{"name":"gossip-tcp","containerPort":9094,"protocol":"TCP"},{"name":"gossip-udp","containerPort":9094,"protocol":"UDP"}]
        io.kubernetes.container.restartCount -> 0
        io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePath -> /dev/termination-log
        io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePolicy -> File
        io.kubernetes.pod.terminationGracePeriod -> 30

And then I wanted to use runc to start a shell within the container:
root@aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss000003:/# runc --root /run/containerd/runc/k8s.io/ exec --tty --user 0 6439882b3402a66761dde073c60721cca3ce89f9e2332a9ca4da3e8cbb268dec sh
FATA[0000] nsexec-1[636535]: failed to open /proc/29605/ns/ipc: Permission denied
FATA[0000] nsexec-0[636532]: failed to sync with stage-1: next state: Success
ERRO[0000] exec failed: unable to start container process: error executing setns process: exit status 1

Then I found another commandline option, using ctr but I got another error there:
root@aks-agentpool-14577650-vmss000003:/# ctr -n k8s.io task exec --user 0 --exec-id 0 --fifo-dir /tmp -t 6439882b3402a66761dde073c60721cca3ce89f9e2332a9ca4da3e8cbb268dec sh
ctr: failed to unmount /tmp/containerd-mount3662884625: operation not permitted: failed to mount /tmp/containerd-mount3662884625: permission denied

I'm stuck here, is it possible to access a container in a pod in an AKS cluster as root?
PS: I know there are several questions like this out there but none of the solutions I found so far seem to work.

Remember that anything you do with kubectl exec will be lost as soon as the Pod is deleted and recreated, and sometimes this happens outside your control (is your AKS setup running the cluster autoscaler, or is the node pool otherwise managed by Azure?).  Also remember that you frequently have multiple replicas of a Deployment, and kubectl exec will only affect one of them.  I'd avoid any sort of routine use of kubectl exec, especially for "normal Linux system administration tasks".  What are you trying to do, and can you modify the image to do it on its own?

This is quite tricky - the solution is to run ctr with the parameter --user 0:0 instead of just --user 0. (I am not fully sure why the group id is needed here, but it works with it.)
So this should work:
ctr -n k8s.io task exec --user 0:0 --exec-id 0 --fifo-dir /tmp -t 6439882b3402a66761dde073c60721cca3ce89f9e2332a9ca4da3e8cbb268dec sh

Just tried this with my test cluster:
root@aks-usernodepl-14294476-vmss00000J:/# ctr -n k8s.io task exec -t --exec-id 0  87b20ec9ee77e1ff68efe4b9e7adbdba07fc40adc9ac7a65f301d140db9d03a0 id
uid=1002(cnb) gid=1000(cnb) groups=1000(cnb)
root@aks-usernodepl-14294476-vmss00000J:/# ctr -n k8s.io task exec -t --user 0:0 --exec-id 0  87b20ec9ee77e1ff68efe4b9e7adbdba07fc40adc9ac7a65f301d140db9d03a0 id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)


Thank you, that solved it. Nice one!
